# Including an image in PHP

Tags: php, image, xampp

I have the following code to cycle through a dataset retrieved from a query:

```
while ($cdata = pg_fetch_array($q_clients)) {    
    echo "<tr><td>$cdata[clientid]</td><td>$cdata[firstname]</td><td>$cdata[lastname]</td><td>$cdata[ip]</td><td>$cdata[status]</td><td><img style=\"cursor: crosshair;\" src=\"../images/delete.png\" onClick=\"window.open('index.php?view=list_client&clientid=$cdata[clientid]&delete=1')\"></td></tr>";
}
```

As you can see, it includes the image `delete.png`. I've put it under `/images/` in my NetBeans project but it still doesn't get loaded. I get a big question mark saying the image cannot be found. When I look at the image source, it points to `localhost/images/delete.png`. The website is built on a XAMPP server.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

On the homepage; I use this code which loads in the background, and actually works perfectly... weird

```
 <body 
    background ="../img/bg.png">
```

Comment: If your image is being echoed in an file that's on the root you don't need the `../` before it

Comment: What's the root path of your php application?

Comment: On MacOSX, it's in the /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs folder

Comment: In image path Projectfolder name is missing like http://localhost/<projectFolder>/images/delete.png

Comment: Check out the edit I have made.

Comment: I know, but they are in separate directories for a reason. That's unfortunately not the thing :-)

Comment: @FDL: Nope, it will produce a `T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE` error. See https://eval.in/60156

Comment: `../img/` and `../images/`? Any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert image is easier for you to specify the absolute path. So you do not run the risk of getting lost in the directories.

**Example:** `http://localhost/myproject/images/delete.png`

Comment: Thank you. I've added the complete URL and escaped it, works perfectly fine now.